# Rails Complex Grouping by Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am creating a custom form builder.

A **Form** has_many **Sections**.

A **Section** has_many **Fields**.

A **Field** has_many **User_Values**.

There is a column on the **User_Values** table called **cloned_index**. I use this for when a user makes a duplicate of a section but need to keep the sections unique.

**My Question:**

Can someone help me write a query that for every section, group the fields by the cloned_index of the field's user values.

**I Currently Have:**

```
form.sections.each do |section| section.fields.each do|field|
  field.user_values.group_by(&:cloned_index)
end
```

This currently doesn't work and is very tough to follow. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this that I'm just not seeing right now.

Comment: It seems to me that the data model is what's causing this complication.  Are you restricted to that model?  I'd recommend adding bridge table between field and user_values.  You can also take advantage of `through` relationships too.  A form could `has_many :fields,  through: :section` for example.  If you explain the business problem, I can probably give a better recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

```
form.sections.joins(fields: [:user_values]).group("user_values.cloned_index")
```

You need to `join` the tables to group them together. The above query will return the `sections` grouped by `cloned_index`

If you want to group the `fields` along with `sections` then try

```
fields.joins(:user_values,:section]).where({sections: {form_id: form.id}}).group("sections.id , user_values.cloned_index")
```

This will return fields of the form grouped by `section ID` and `cloned_index`